# 'Length' method of an ActiveRecord query returns error when the size of the result is 1. How can I check if this is the case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I do this:

```
 a = User.all
 a.length # 15
```

It works, I get 15. But, if for some reason my query returns only one value ...

```
 a = User.find(1)
 a.length # NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for #<User:0x007f00815f9e38>
```

Which is logical, there's only one result. Is there a method that can check if the result is 1?

## EDIT:

I'll explain what I'm trying to do. I want to know if a certain query returns 1 or more records. I'd try this with count, length or size, but all of those methods aren't available when the query returns only a single record. I need to know when I get one record and when there's more, but I can't figure out how to measure this without getting 'nomethod' errors on both scenarios.

```
 # There're 15 users active right now.
 a=User.find_by(:active => true)
 a.length                        # 15

 # Only 1 user is active.
 a=User.find_by(:active => true)
 a.length                        # Nomethod Error
```

## SOLUTION:

I was using the `find_by` method, which doesn't seem to include the `size, count, length` methods in the result. As suggested below, I used `where` instead, and the result now included the size methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
User.all
```

the result is an *array*, and thus has a `length` method.

In contrast, when you call either of

```
User.find(1)
```

or

```
User.find_by(active: true)
```

the result is either a single `User` instance or `nil`, neither of which have a `length` method. Since `find` does a lookup against the backing table's unique id, you'll never get back more than one result.

As a further contrast, if your `User` model defined a boolean called `active` you could write:

```
User.where(active: true)
```

... and that would return an array that you can use with `count` or `length`.

In general, when you're looking for the number of rows that correspond to some condition, I would use

```
Model.where(conditions).count
```

... as this is reliable and generates a single query (`SELECT COUNT(*) ...`) without instantiating any models.

Comment: That was merely an example. I'm doing a query that looks something like this: `a=User.find_by(:active => true)` sometimes I get 15, sometimes I get 5, but there're times I get one, and when I do, the whole instance crashes cause I cannot compare the length of a single record.

Comment: Try using `where` instead of `find_by` as above.

Comment: Also, the doc for `find_by` says "Finds the first record matching the specified conditions." So I'm surprised that you're able to use `count` or `length` on it anyway. I suspect that's an unintended consequence of the way it's implemented.

Comment: Bingo! The where made the difference, it works now. And yes, this is an old implementation, I think at some point it wasn't doing this.

Comment: That makes sense. I've never used find_by (or seen it used before, for that matter). Glad it works now.

Comment: Mind elaborating this in your answer? So I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `count`. The difference between them is described [here](http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/).

Comment: Already tried that. Still the same result: `NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for #<User:0x007f00815f9e38>`

Answer (score 0):

Doing `Foo.find(:id)` you're basically telling ActiveRecord you just want to know about that 1 foo, you're not bothered about it's size or count because you already know it.

This is my irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> u = User.all
irb(main):002:0> u.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
=> 18
irb(main):003:0> u.length
=> 18
irb(main):004:0> u.size
=> 18
```

All great, I do have 18 users.
This is my console when I try to do a `count` from a `find`

```
irb(main):005:0> u1 = User.find(1)
irb(main):006:0> u1.length
NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for #<User:0x00000002dbc9a8>
```

Smashing, we're on the same page now.

Now, this is what happens when I have 1 user from a collection/array.

```
irb(main):031:0> u.count
  (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
=> 1
irb(main):032:0> u.size
=> 1
irb(main):033:0> u.length
=> 1
irb(main):034:0>
```

Becaue I'm querying a collection/array of records instead of a single one, I don't get the error.

So, Foo.all will return an array and give you access to `count, size and length` while Foo.find returns a single object.

Edit:

If `find_by` returns nil or undefined method you could write your query like so: `Foo.where(active: true)` ..